# WHERE conditions in created columns in SQL

Tags: sql

How do you only show the 'MISSING AREA' data instead of including the blanks if the areas.id are empty? I tried using where outlet.STATUS <> 0 but SQL said the column STATUS does not exist. So in this case my created STATUS column cannot be filtered?

Sorry for the confusion, a sample data will be something like:

**Shops**

```
id  firm name area id              
----------------------
1   abc       21              
2   xyz       23             
3   def       42
```

**Areas**

```
id  
--
20  
23   
40
```

Joined tables with STATUS:

```
id  firm name area_id id   Status   
---------------------------------------
1   abc       21      NULL MISSING AREA   
2   xyz       23      23     
3   def       42      NULL MISSING AREA
```

I wish to not show shops.id = 2 and just display 1 and 3

```
select 
    shops.id, shops.firm_name, shops.area_id, 
    areas.id, 
    IF(areas.id, "", "MISSING AREA") as STATUS 
from 
    shops
left join 
    areas on areas.id = shops.area_id
where 
    shops.area_id != 0 
order by 
    STATUS asc
```

Comment: Please tag DBMS and provide some sample and output data,  I think it's very easy requirement.

Comment: You mention `outlet.STATUS <> 0`, and the query has `outlets.area_id != 0`, 2 different spellings for `outlet`. Either way, what is this `outlet`?  I don't see `outlet` referenced anywhere in the `from`, `join` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to filter on a calculated column, you have two options:

- **Repeat the column expression inside the `WHERE` clause** - this is not ideal, because of code repetition.
- **Wrap the `SELECT` with calculated column in another `SELECT`, and filter the outer one** - this lets you use a single expression for a slightly longer query.

Here is an example of the second approach:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        shops.id
    ,   shops.firm_name
    ,   shops.area_id
    ,   areas.id
    ,   CASE WHEN areas.id is NULL THEN 'MISSING AREA' END as STATUS
    FROM shops
    LEFT JOIN areas ON areas.id = shops.area_id
)
WHERE ... -- You can use STATUS here
ORDER BY STATUS
```